# Как отсортировать массив по полю?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [order] => 0, [value] = text1
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [order] => 2, [value] = text3
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [order] => 1, [value] = text2
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [order] => 4, [value] = text5
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [order] => 3, [value] = text4
     )
```

Как можно его отсортировать по полю order ? чтобы они встали по порядку от 0 до 4

Comment: Простите, у вашего массива одинаковые идексы?

Comment: @rjhdby тут массив объектов, а не многомерный массив

Comment: @SamuelLoog иррелевантно

Comment: Из ваших одинаковых индексов будет отрабатывать только первый

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php).

```
// $objArray - ваш массив, передается по ссылке 
usort($objArray, function($obj1, $obj2) {
    if ($obj1->order == $obj2->order) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $obj1->order < $obj2->order ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: всю жизнь возвращали `return l.value - r.value` зачем такие сложности с `if`ами?

Comment: ну или в данном случае `function($obj1, $obj2){ return $obj1->value - $obj2->value; }`

Comment: да, соглашусь с teran: тело функции можно сократить до
    `return $obj1->order - $obj2->order;`

но при условии, что разность $obj1->order и $obj2->order не выходит за рамки диапазона с -2147483648 по 2147483647.